# Machine learning and Security

Tags: security

I would like to ask you if it is possible to secure a server with AI/machine learning based on the following concepts:

1) the server is implemented in a way to recognize a normal behavior(authorized access, modification, ...) .

2) the server must recognize any abnormal behavior and adapt to it if encountered.

3) if an abnormal behavior is caught, it checks in some kind of pre-known threat list what type of threat it is and a possible solution for it ELSE it adapts "by itself"  and perform changes based on what the normal behavior must be.

PS: If there already is a system similar to this one please let me know.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Current IDS/IPS systems for applications ("web application firewalls") are in part similar to this (the other part is usually plain pattern matching to find common or known attacks or attack classes). First you switch a WAF to "learning mode", it listens to traffic and stores patterns as *normal* behavior. Then you switch it to "prevention mode" and it stops any traffic that is out of the ordinary flow.

The key is what aspects of the dataflows they listen to and learn to try and find anomalies. Basically a WAF would look at http queries to pages, learn parameter types and length, maybe clients as well, and in prevention mode it would not allow a type or length mismatch (any request not matching the learned values would be stopped on the WAF).

There are obvious drawbacks to this, the learning phase can never be long enough, learnt rules will either be too generic or too specific, manual setup is tedious for a large application, etc.

Taking it to a more generic level would be very (**very**) difficult. Maybe with a deep neural network (so popular nowadays) you could better approximate a "real" AI that actually learns good and bad traffic patterns. Two obvious problems are getting patterns to teach it (how will you provide good and bad traffic examples in excessive amounts so that it can actually learn the difference) and operational cost (running such a deep neural network would be very expensive, probably way more than a typical application breach would cost - defenses should be proportionate to the risk).

Having said that, I think it's not impossible, but it will take a few years until we get there.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is interesting and there is a lot of research on this topic currently: https://github.com/Limmen/awesome-rl-for-cybersecurity

But it's still quite far from being mature enough to use in practical settings.